# React - Add user to list of Favorites

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple user list with several details from the following api: https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users, where I want to add a selected user to a list of favorites. I am working with react-router to navigate between pages. Is this possible with React or do I also need Redux?

I have a complete [LIVE EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-feather-8l6kn) here with the user page and favorites.

Here is the code below for the user list:

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import NavLinks from "./components/navLink";

export default class UserList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [],
      addToFav: false
    };
    this.list = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getList();
  }

  /* get users list */
  getList = async () => {
    const api =
      "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users?_format=json&access-token=3qIi1MDfD-GXqOSwEHHLH73Y3UitdaFKyVm_";

    await axios
      .get(api)
      .then(response => {
        this.list = response.data.result;
        this.setState({
          list: this.list
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  addToFav = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        addToFav: !this.state.addToFav
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.addToFav)
    );
  };

  render() {
    let style = {
      display: "grid",
      gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr))",
      padding: "1rem",
      gridGap: "1rem 1rem"
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <NavLinks />
        <ul style={style}>
          {this.state.list.map(user => {
            return (
              <li key={user.id}>
                <div>
                  <img className="thumb" alt="" src={user._links.avatar.href} />
                </div>

                <div className="userInfo">
                  <p>
                    {user.first_name} {user.last_name}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.addToFav}>Add to Favorites</button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You provided a goal but no specific problem or question related to achieving that goal? What is your question?

Comment: Since the list of favorites has to be accessed by both routes, the simplest way is to put it in your main app's `state`, then pass it to the favorites Route. Then you pass a method to add a favorite by ID to component that displays the entire list.

Comment: If your application is small then you can achieve it without using redux but if you have more complex requirement it would be better to use react

Comment: Yes, use a UsersContext.Provider above your routes.
and when you need them, just useContext or a Consumer
What react version you are using?

Comment: My application is indeed small. I have only found examples using Redux, that is why I ask this question. I don't have the slightest idea to do it only with React.

Comment: I am using the latest version @MohamedELAYADI

Comment: Okey, there are plenty of ways to do this, using only react. Are you familiar with hooks ?

Comment: I'm rather new with hooks, tbh. @MohamedELAYADI

Comment: What do you mean, "you don't have the slightest idea"? Add the state and addFav method to your main app, then pass them as props to the children, as required. Where exactly is the issue? Don't mean to be rude, just curious where exactly you're stuck. In case you're wondering how to pass props to routes: `component={() => <UserList prop={value} />}`

Comment: Thank you for the help Chris. I'm just stuck on the part on how I put a selected user to the favorite list. I understand how to pass props. @ChrisG

Comment: The list needs to be an array, and part of the app component's `state`. Next you need to pass the id when the user clicks the button, so you know which user to add. `onClick={() => this.props.addToFav(user.id)}`. Append to the array. Finally, pass the array to the favorites route component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-fire-4kd4p

This train of thought pretty much follows what @Chris G mentioned. Have a top-level state that holds the list of users and the favorites list. Then pass those as props to the individual components.

**App.js**

Hit your API here instead of inside your UserList component to prevent any unnecessary re-renders.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import UserList from "./userList";
import FavoriteList from "./favoriteList";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    list: [],
    favorites: []
  };

  addFavorite = favorite => {
    const { favorites } = this.state;

    if (!favorites.some(alreadyFavorite => alreadyFavorite.id == favorite.id)) {
      this.setState({
        favorites: [...this.state.favorites, favorite]
      });
    }
  };

  getList = async () => {
    const api =
      "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users?_format=json&access-token=3qIi1MDfD-GXqOSwEHHLH73Y3UitdaFKyVm_";

    await axios
      .get(api)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          list: response.data.result
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getList();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/"
        exact
        render={() => (
          <UserList list={this.state.list} addFavorite={this.addFavorite} />
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path="/favorites"
        render={() => <FavoriteList favorites={this.state.favorites} />}
      />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

}
}

**UserList.js**

Call the `addFavorite` event-handler on button-click to pass that item back up to the parent-state.

```
import React from "react";

import NavLinks from "./components/navLink";

export default class UserList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let style = {
      display: "grid",
      gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr))",
      padding: "1rem",
      gridGap: "1rem 1rem"
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <NavLinks />
        <ul style={style}>
          {this.props.list.map(user => {
            return (
              <li key={user.id}>
                <div>
                  <img className="thumb" alt="" src={user._links.avatar.href} />
                </div>

                <div className="userInfo">
                  <p>
                    {user.first_name} {user.last_name}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.addFavorite(user)}>
                  Add to Favorites
                </button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Favorite.js**

Use the `favorites` array that was passed in as a prop and iterate over it.

```
import React from "react";

import NavLinks from "./components/navLink";

export default class FavoriteList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { favorites } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <NavLinks />
        <ul>
          {favorites.map(user => {
            return (
              <li key={user.id}>
                <div>
                  <img className="thumb" alt="" src={user._links.avatar.href} />
                </div>

                <div className="userInfo">
                  <p>
                    {user.first_name} {user.last_name}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible with React or do I also need Redux?

Most if not all of those problems can be solved without `redux` just by using component state. It just gets increasingly difficult to pass the state to the components needing it the more global state you have and the more components at different depth need to access and update it.

In your case it might be sufficient to store the favorites in a component state high up the tree and pass it to the components consuming it. You could either pass it directly to the components or you could use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to make it accessible to components deep in the tree.

**A simple example:**

```
const FavoritesContext = React.createContext({favorites: []});

const FavoritesProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]);

    const add = useCallback(favorite => setFavorites(current => [...current, favorite]), [setFavorites]);

    return (
        <FavoritesContext.Provider value={{favorites, add}}>
            {children}
        </FavoritesContext.Provider>
};
```

You can use it like that:

```
<FavoritesProvider>
    <MyApp />
</FavoritesProvider>
```

then anywhere in a component in your app:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const {favorites, add} = useContext(FavoritesContext);

    const [draft, setDraft] = useState('');

    const handleChange = event => setDraft(event.target.value);
    const handleAdd = () => {
        add(draft);
        setDraft('');
    };

    return (
      <div>
          <ul>
              {favorites.map(favorite => <li>{favorite}</li>)}
          </ul>
          <input value={draft} type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
          <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
      </div>
    );
}
```

In this simple example the favorites are just text but they could as well be objects. Also it demonstrates how you could provide a handler for adding a favorite. You could implement e.g. a handler for removing favorites in the same way.

Persisting your favorites is yet another topic you may need to deal with. You could use e.g. localStorage for that or you could store that in a database on a server and fetch it when your app mounts the first time.

Comment: So, I create this `<FavoritesProvider>` in a separate file and then I can put my `<App/>` inside it? @trixn

Comment: @RCohen Basically yes. The provider injects a context into the tree below it. Everything that gets rendered into the provider then has access to it by using `useContext` or rendering a context consumer. You only need to put everything inside it that needs to access the favorites. It doesn't have to be the whole app but often it will be.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try your solution. @trixn

Comment: @RCohen Also note that while I used react hooks here it can also be done without hooks but then it requires a context consumer which you can render. You can get details in the react docs.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your file a bit take a look - https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-butterfly-vb2iz

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the localstorage of browser.

But this way is slighty expensive and synchronous.

Update the list whenever the favorited item status is changed via

```
localStorage.setItem('users',JSON.stringify(users));
```

And look for the favorited items via

```
localStorage.getItem('users');//You need to parse this by JSON.parse()
```

Maintain a `isFavorite` variable in the object list.

```
let users=[{name:"Mr.A",isFavorite:false},{name:"Mr.B",isFavorite:true},...];
```

On the click of favoriting button `this.addToFav` change it as follows

```
addToFav=user=>{
  const {users}=this.state;
  this.setState({
    users:users.map(userObject=>userObject.id===user.id? 
  {...userObject,isFavorite:!userObject.isFavorite}:user)
    },()=>{saveToLocal(this.state.users)});
}
```

Now you can access the favorite items even if the page is reloaded and stays there till you clear the storage.Use this `localStorage.clear()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

First I would change your onClick to this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.addToFav(user.id)}>Add to Favorites</button>
```

This will allow you to pass the id to the addToFave function.
Then I would add a new state called faves (an array) and every time someone clicks the add button I would add their id into this array. This will allow you to filter your original list when you want to display the faves.

```
  this.state = {
      list: [],
      faves: [],
    };
  }

  addToFav = (id) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        faves: [...prevState.faves, id],
    }));
  };
```

When I want to use the list of faves instead of the normal list I would do this:

```
const favesList = [];
this.state.list.map(listItem => 
    this.state.faves.find(
        faveId => listItem.id === faveId
    ) && favesList.push(item);
```

Then I would pass that to the faves component

Comment: The question is primarily about setting favorites in one route, and displaying them in another (this is why OP is asking whether they need redux). Your answer doesn't address that.

Answer (score 0):

I changed accordingly, please try

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-poincare-7oeh0

the key is you can use push state to your link like below

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/favorites", state: { favList: this.props.favList }}} onClick={() => this.forceUpdate()}>
```

later on under your fav page call to retrieve the state

```
this.props.location.state.favList
```

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the code a little  by using react context.
I would not use redux for this cause i think it would be a overkill.
Anyways here is the updated sandbox...

[Link for sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-kirch-3vd17?fontsize=14)